# Latest BerryBoot 2.0 Bluetooth issues

Tags: bluetooth, pi-3, berryboot

I installed the latest Raspbian Jessie 1.9 on my Raspberry Pi 3, with the latest version 2.0 of BerryBoot.

When I install that same Raspbian version (*downloaded from the Raspberry site*) in the normal way - no problems, everything works fine.

When I install that version (*according to the BerryBoot-menu*) through BerryBoot, I have lot of issues with Bluetooth. Difficult to connect. Connections on and off, more off than on. So, not useable.

I sometimes get this error message:

> You might not be able to connect to the Bluetooth network via this machine org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ExecFailed: Failed to execute program org.blueman.Mechanism: Success"

But no success at all.

Has someone else experienced this problem? Any idea how to solve it?

(*Apparently, the Bluetooth-function is not from Raspbian here, but BerryBoot...*).

Comment: It is not unusual for Berryboot to cause problems like this, did Bluetooth work with the non Berryboot install?

Comment: Bluetooth works really good (almost perfect: just PAN not working - but the reason can be with Windows). Connection is well maintained, reconnect at startup, etc. Its just with Berryboot that I have the problem...

Answer (score 1):

Same issue; found the answer after several searches:

A permission has gotten set improperly somehow; this fixed it for me:

chmod o+x /usr/lib/dbus-1.0/dbus-daemon-launch-helper

Comment: Thanks Bill, I'll try that during the week-end and will post the result!